# JavaScript Memory: Heap, Native, WebGL/GPU

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, memory

Is it possible to see all sources of memory for JavaScript in Chrome?  As far as I know the three above are what would be available.

The Heap is your basic GC-able JS objects.  "Native Memory" is not part of the Heap .. like DOM, TypedArrays, 2D context ImageData and so on.  WebGL too is a source of memory.

I'd like to know how much my code is using.  Chrome recently dumped their Native profiler. Heap profiling is simply not sufficient for large memory web-apps.

Is there a way to get useful information on what percent of these memory sources my code is using?

Comment: Have you used the developer tools (F12) and clicked on the `Profiles` tab?

Comment: Yup. I tend to use Canary, so may differ from stable Chrome.  Paul Irish had a Native Profiler experiment, but it was yanked quite recently.  Its possible to see that a Heap object is a wrapper for a Native (i.e. C/C++ chrome native data structure), and will thus be GCed, but you can't see how much Native memory is attached, nor how much Native memory you have available.  I think I've got that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I estimate the native memory by using the chrome task manager (more tools | Task Manager). It shows the private memory, GPU memory and javascript memory. `private memory - javascript memory` would be an approximation of native memory. But it can't indicate how much memory is allocated by different kinds of resources.

It also shows the GPU memory if the page has a canvas.

[image: chrome task manager]

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the best we have for the moment. Chrome tried a native memory profile a while back (Paul Irish, I believe) but it didn't last.

Comment: I just discovered "chrome://tracing" can show a bit more details about how memory is used if you select the "memory-infra" flag